# How to implement OnException and errorHandler in a camel route and spring boot?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I would like to use `onExceptionProcessor` to catch any exceptions catched by my route builder and save them in the database.

I don't khnow if i have to use onException(Exception.class) or errorHandler() and how to implement them correctly!

I tried the try-catch but it does not catch my exception (null pointer that i throw in the processor1). May be i do not implement it correctly ?

Here is my routeBuilder:

```
@component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Autowired
  private Processor processor1;  

  @Autowired
  private Processor procssor2;  

  @Autowired
  private Processor processor3;

  @Autowired
  private Processor onExceptionProcessor; // it a processor where i try to save the stacktrace of exception in the database

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(jmsDecoupageRouteIn)
        .id("route_id_processing").messageHistory().transacted()
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, log, "It's for just for log").pipeline()
        .process(processor1)
        .id(processor1.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .process(procssor2)
        .id(procssor2.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .process(processor3)
        .id(processor3.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .doTry()
        .to(jmsDecoupageRouteOut)
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "EXCEPTION: ${exception.stacktrace}")
        .process(onExceptionProcessor)
        .id(onExceptionProcessor.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase())
        .endDoTry();
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  The documentation has https://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html and https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

Comment: @RichardNeish i've edited my post , because i've tried the try catch clause but still not catching the error

Comment: OK,  In the code you have in your post, doTry() and doCatch are only around the ".to(jmsDecoupageRouteOut)" line.  If you want to catch an exception in processor1 you should put .doTry() before this step in the route.

Comment: I did it and it works but the issue is how to catch the message error in the processor ? have you any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the generic structure of a `doTry()...doCatch()...end()` construct.

```
 from("direct:start")
                    .doTry()
                        .process(new ProcessorFail())
                        .to("mock:result")
                    .doCatch(IOException.class, IllegalStateException.class)
                        .to("mock:catch")
                    .doFinally()
                        .to("mock:finally")
                    .end();
```

In your case you are using a `.endDoTry()` instead of `.end()`. Its a tiny gotcha in the Camel API. Change it and see if it works as expected.

Additional Reference

- [A test case for similar construct](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/TryProcessorMultipleExceptionTest.java)
- [Docs for doTry()...doCatch()...end()](https://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html)

Keep in mind that when you use `doTry()...doCatch()...end()` the regular Camel `OnException` handlers will not work (You can't mix them together).

Update: Screenshot as shared with OP
[image: Exception handling processor definition]

Comment: I do not need a to('') in the catch but just a processor where i catch the message exception.but i do not khnow how to do that, have any idea ?

Comment: Use a `.process( yourProcessor )` instead of `.to()`. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Yes, it works but if i want to catch the exception message in the processor, i did like : `Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)` but i got an error 500 and not the nullPointerException that i am looking for

Comment: I would like to catch the stackTrace in my `OnExceptionProcessor` to save it in the database and not just to logging it :)

Comment: Hold on. Booting a test env ;)

Comment: I have tried reproducing [this](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/TryProcessorMultipleExceptionTest.java) test case with a `.process()` instead of a `.to()` and it works as expected. See screenshot [on imgur](https://imgur.com/a/yU3xO7S).

How about setting a break point on your `onExceptionProcessor` class's `.process()` method and inspecting what is coming into the processor?